# Leaflet layer tree plugin - overlays unvisible after base layer switch

Tags: leaflet, plugins

having the same problem as [Leaflet layer tree plugin - order layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187528/leaflet-layer-tree-plugin-order-layers), i installed the solution but that does not work for me:

added zIndex:10 to the base layers

```
            code: "base",
            name: "Base Layers",
            active: true,
            selectedByDefault: false,
            openByDefault: true,
            childLayers: [
                {
                    code: "osm",
                    name: "OpenStreetMap.org",
                    active: true,
                    selectedByDefault: true,
                    openByDefault: true,
                    childLayers: [],
                    selectType: "NONE",
                    serviceType: "OSM",
                    params: {
                        url: osmOrgUrl,
                        attribution: osmTiles,
                        zIndex:10,
                        maxNativeZoom:19,
                        maxZoom:20
                    }
                },
                {
                    code: "osm_gray",
                    name: "OpenstreetMap.org gray",
                    active: true,
                    selectedByDefault: false,
                    openByDefault: true,
                    childLayers: [],
                    selectType: "NONE",
                    serviceType: "OSM_GRAY",
                    params: {
                        zIndex: 10
                    }
                }
```

...

and zIndex:10000 to the overlays

```
                        {
                           code: "fire_hydrants",
                           name: "Hydrants",
                           active: true,
                           selectedByDefault: false,
                           openByDefault: true,
                           childLayers: [],
                           selectType: "MULTIPLE",
                           serviceType: "WMS",
                           coordinateSystem: "EPSG:4326",
                           onPopup: function (layer) {
                               return buildContentFromLayer(layer);
                           },
                           params: {
                               request: "getMap",
                               service: "WMS",
                               layers:  "osm:Hydrants",
                               name: "Hydrants",
                               version: "1.1.0",
                               url: geosWMS,
                               format: "image/png8",
                               transparent: true,
                               zIndex: 10000,
                               maxFeatures: "1000"
                           },
                        },
```

...

but nothing changed :(

page is online: https://wambachers-osm.website/emergency/idx400.jsp

select Hydrants as overlay and then switch base layers.

Answer (score -1):

"Solved" this problem by switching from Leaflet layer tree plugin to jstree.

Comment: It might help others if you could provide links to the plugins you reference, in case they have the same problem. :)